# Issue installing Tex Live on Windows 10

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

Yesterday I installed a clean version of Windows 10 after the update and the format.

Today I was trying install Tex Live but there is an issue. The installer (exe) unzipped the file but then simply shut down when I pressed close and did not start the installation process itself.

The zipped version of the installer (the alternate method cited on the tex live site) opened the CMD successfully, but then a window said that there are some problems with perl and with every press key shut down.

Then I tried with the 2015 live cd, the error is the same as the CMD.

The other programs and drivers are perfect; Tex Live is the only one that caused me trouble.

Is it the same for you or is it just me? Are there some fixes that I can try or I just need to wait for an updated version of the Tex Live suite compatible with Windows 10?

Sorry for the bad English!

Comment: What about the recommended network install?

Comment: The network install is not the installer/zip folder (12/16 mb)? I downloaded both and they act like i reported.
Then i tried the whole package (the 2015 iso about 2GB) but unsuccessfully... the iso open the CMD (like the zip archive) but then an "alarm" window pop up and the CMD shut down with every key.

The only thing thatopen is the installer, but after the autounzip (the process with the green writings) remains still and if i click on close simply shut down not starting the installation process itself.

Comment: Did you try downloading he `install-tl-zip` and then use the `install-tl-advanced.bat` installer? I'm waiting for the win10, so I currently cannot test. However, it will be an upgrade, and I already have TL15 on this PC.

Comment: Same problem with the advanced bat.
The prompt start and after only one line of code (with perl gui involved) a pop up said that is impossible to open the application.
I close the popup and then the CMD make another line code: "press any key to continue". With enter (or any key) the prompt shut down.

The same with live cd (iso).

Mine too was an upgrade, but after that i clean-installed after a format to "smooth" things...

Comment: The only thing I can think is that there is a issue with perl (is what the prompt looking to start). With the live cd and with the zip folder I can see the CMD.
I think that with the installer the process simply not start at all for a similar reason (I cannot see the prompt with the executable version).

Comment: Of course TeX Live has some advantages over MiKTeX, but on Windows, I think MiKTeX is more friendly and auto update is just one click away!

Comment: I haven't tried on Windows 10 yet, but I've seen similar Perl errors on Windows 7 in the past. See if going to a command prompt and running `install-tl.bat -no-gui` works.

Comment: Tomorrow I'm going to try with MiKTeX but onestly I prefer Tex Live for the support of a particular community of my University.

I have tried to install the batch file directly via prompt with the "-no-gui" line but the result is the same.

When i install the windows.bat the prompt doesn't stamp at screen the line with perl, but the alert pop up with the same message "cannot start correctly the application"
With the advanced.bat the pop up is the same but in the CMD there is the perl thing.

The error code of the pop up is: "0xc0000142" for both advanced and windows bat.
The same with no gui.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255803/how-long-will-it-take-tex-live-to-fit-windows-10#comment612341_255803) the public pretest worked. (Although that doesn't mean the installer, of course.)

Comment: Well all the program after the update worked... the problem is the installation (only for the tex suite) after the wipe and the clean installation.
However, this morning i tried the installer and the zip a second time, same result.
I tried execute the bat file via command line, same result.
I tried execute via command line with the option of the text gui, same result.

Comment: Then I tried install Strawberry Perl and copy the lib and data into the zip archive of Tex Live, the installation start but then the CMD stamp a ton of command line with all the incongruity. I aspect that, but effectively the installation start without the popup of perl crashing.

Later i'm going to try the same thing but with the data and lib of the perl version of the Live CD version of Tex Live.
Is the only thing that i can think now.

However i think that the problem is the Perl program included for the Windows package of Tex Live (in the installer and in the archive too).

Comment: I have Windows 10 and obtained `texlive2015` from `http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2015.iso` after which I mounted it with ultraiso and ran `install-tl-windows.bat` in admin mode. TeXLive 2015 installed fine for me.

Comment: @azetina @ OP 64 bit or 32 bit TeX Live? There might be a difference?

Comment: I tried again with the texlive2015 iso in admin mode. Same result. Perl.exe crash at the first code line in the CMD.
I think that paste the perl lib and bin in the downlodable archive from the iso is pointless.

@ cfr I have the 64bit version of Windows 10 Home.

Comment: @cfr Windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: @azetina Thanks. So it presumably can't be the version of perl per se? (I know nothing about Windows, mind. Just if it works on one system and not the other...?) @ OP Have you seen if there is anything on the TL mailing list and, if not, asked there? They are more likely to know than anybody - especially Norbert, I suspect.

Comment: Well, i know nothing too of perl. In the old system the past installation work fine. I'm a Biologist and i use tex for university only for writing papers, I know a very little about other programming language or system...
I found this community while i was searching for a fix.
How can I access the TL mailing list?

Comment: @DrewEugene17 Details linked from [here], together with documentation - you probably want to check for known problems before mailing them.

Comment: @cfr, `[here]` without a link?

Comment: My test laptop just got the upgrade. I uninstalled TL15 before the upgrade, and sucessfully installed TL15 afterwards (using the `.zip`and the advanced `.bat`). @DrewEugene17 can you give more information about your system? Perhaps language plays a role.

Comment: @daleif [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) is what I meant ;). I think.

Comment: @cfr given the limited experience with win10, that known issues page does not help much. And I think most of it have already been suggested.

Comment: @daleif I was responding to the OP's question `How can I access the TL mailing list?` The main point was the mailing list information. The suggestion to double-check the documentation first was just standard advice.

Comment: Thanks for the mailing list link.

@daleif I have a HP tablet PC (touchsmart 2) with a clean installation of Windows 10 Home x64 Italian.
The pc was upgraded and the wiped two times after the clean installation.
I don't know why this happen after the clean installation too... I wiped for this reason and everithing run smooth. Everything but Tex Live.
I searched for this type of error (and about the dll) but after two wipe-and-clean installation is very strange...
I can imagine about old system with registry issue but not on a fresh system.

Comment: @cfr How can I reply on the mailing list? I posted the problem and i saw the reply in the august archive thread but i can't find an option to reply in the "archive three". I see only the text.

Comment: You have to register. Only registered members can post and reply. Remember to register with the email address you are sending from

Answer (score 8):

I just tested with a brand-new wx pro 64-bits and an advanced user install and had no problems. To be exact: I downloaded the exe, selected the unpack option and after it finished unpacking I double-clicked install-tl-advanced.bat, but clicking the advanced button also started up the main installer interface.

I searched for this "0xc0000142" error. Unfortunately it seems a pretty intractable beast.

As a workaround, you can try a portable install on a usb stick from another computer.

Comment: This is not really an answer, is it?

Comment: @cfr It is an answer, of course! We know now that you can install without error on Win 10.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try with a portable installation from another PC.
If I install on the PC MiKTeX and then on the pen drive Tex Live can they go in conflict?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across the same set of errors. The solution to me was, after one day of searching the whole wide interwebs, to

**RUN UNDER WINDOWS 7 COMPATIBILTY MODE.**

That's it. I have no clue why so ever it does not work with a fresh Windows 10 installation, I am just a plebb, but the compatibility mode worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Right click either `install-tl-advanced.bat` or `install-tl-windows.bat` and select "Run as Administrator".